# send a file FROM node js

Tags: node.js, file, https

I've read a million different pages on how to send a file to node js from some client, but that is NOT what I'm looking for. I'd like to send a file from out client side code to a 3rd party storage system, but they don't account for the options preflight method and there is nothing I can do about that, nor can I use a different 3rd party service.

So what I'd like to do is send a file from the client, to our node js backend service, and then from the service, send the file to the 3rd party. I understand and have done many times, http request from node but I'm always sending an object of some sort. The difference here is that the object I want to send is a file.

**Question**: How do I get a file object together and then send that through an HTTPS PUT?

PS: I'm also running just plain vanilla node js.

Comment: What is this 3rd party storage? Doesn't it expose any API?

Comment: Its an in house thing. I'm given an endpoint url, and I have credentials that I put in the headers that are used to put the file in my account with the request.

Comment: I believe info about this endpoint and why and how is it using the http protocol is necessary to answer the question in full, but if it's anything like a browser, header-wise, I would try the header 'content-disposition' that declares an attachment, or similar - to try and wrap it as a file after sending it.

Comment: I mean, that's a valid point, but away from the main point of the question. I trying to figure out how to send a file object out of Node js.